# How to include Chrome DevTools in Electron?

Tags: electron

I'm still new to Electron which I'm currently following [here](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/quick-start.md).

I've read this [page](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/devtools-extension.md) regarding on how to include the [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) so that I can debug my application easily. I've followed the documentation but once I execute the `electron <app-name>` command it returns an error: `The app provided is not a valid electron app, please read the docs on how to write one...`

Here's the block of code from my `main.js` file:

```js
var app = require('app');
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');

// Add Chrome DevTools extension for debugging
require('remote').require('browser-window').addDevToolsExtension('../react-devtools')
```

That is how my project structure looks like:

```
- react-devtools
- src
  -- index.html
  -- main.js
- package.json
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I know this question is geared towards why this error is showing up, and I am not sure if this differs from the dev tools extension, but try calling the .openDevTools() method on the BrowserWindow object you create and see if that gives you want you are looking for.

Answer (score 56):

Maybe I am misunderstanding, but you can just do <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to pull up dev tools.

Or alternatively if you are wanting to do it programmatically, the way I do it is include the following lines in my `main.js` file that is passed to electron.

```js
var app = require('app');
var BrowserWindows = require('browser-window');
    
app.on('ready', function(){
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width:800, height:600});
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
}
```

I believe part of your problem may be that you aren't waiting for the app to be ready before you try to do stuff with it.

Comment: Where did you come up with Ctrl + Shift + I to open devtools?

Comment: Oh I see - that normally works in Chrome. However, in Electron it won't. You'd need to add a listener for the shortcut. The second part of your answer is correct though

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + I definitely still works up to Electron 2.0.0. I just double checked.

Comment: Huh, I do not observe that behavior. Maybe my settings don't allow it...

Answer (score 21):

So, after you've required the following:

```js
var app = require('app');
```

You can use the following code (I use it in my app):

```js
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('remote-debugging-port', '8315');
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('host-rules', 'MAP * 127.0.0.1');
```

Accessing the following address allows me to debug the application in Chrome:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8315
```

I hope this helps you out. I'm also new to Electron!

If you also need to do some configurations to the underlying browser engine, please, refer to [the docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/command-line-switches.md).

Comment: I found the second line unnecessary and at times causes comms errors. If you don't need it leave it out.

Comment: I just want to add my 2 cents:
1) Usually there is no need to add these lines into JavaScript sources - you can just add --remote-debugging-port=8315 to command line
2) After this open your Chrome/Chromium browser and enter URL chrome://inspect - there you can add localhost:8315 endpoint and connect to it.

Answer (score 4):

### Press F12 to open DevTools when `mainWindow.removeMenu()` was used

`ctrl + shift + i` only works when the electron menu has not been removed. When you removed the menu with `mainWindow.removeMenu()`, you can add this to your main process code, to still be able to open the devtools with F12. To close the devTools with F12 you have to first click into your electron app so that the devtools window looses the focus.

```js
myBrowserWindow.webContents.on('before-input-event', (_, input) => {
    if (input.type === 'keyDown' && input.key === 'F12') {
      myBrowserWindow.webContents.isDevToolsOpened()
        ? myBrowserWindow.webContents.closeDevTools()
        : myBrowserWindow.webContents.openDevTools({ mode: 'left' });
    }
});
```

if you do not need to change the devTools open `mode` you can use this instead:

```js
myBrowserWindow.webContents.on('before-input-event', (_, input) => {
    if (input.type === 'keyDown' && input.key === 'F12') {
      myBrowserWindow.webContents.toggleDevTools();
    }
});
```

for `mode: 'detach'` pressing f12 again will not close the detached window, so you can can use this instead:

```js
myBrowserWindow.webContents.on('before-input-event', (_, input) => {
    if (input.type === 'keyDown' && input.key === 'F12') {
      myBrowserWindow.webContents.openDevTools({ mode: 'detach' });
    }
});
```

source:
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/keyboard-shortcuts#intercepting-events-in-the-main-process

Answer (score 3):

you can open dev tool like this:

```js
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1024, height: 768 });
mainWindow.loadURL('your url');
mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
mainWindow.webContents.on('devtools-opened', () => {
    setImmediate(() => {
        // do whatever you want to do after dev tool completely opened here
        mainWindow.focus();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To enable opening dev tools via key strokes, I added this to my `index.html`:

```html
<script>
    // for electron
    if (typeof require !== 'undefined') {
        const currentWebContents = require('electron').remote.getCurrentWebContents();
        document.addEventListener('keyup', ({ key, ctrlKey, shiftKey, metaKey, altKey }) => {
            if (
                key === 'F12' ||
                (ctrlKey && shiftKey && key === 'I') ||
                (metaKey && altKey && key === 'i')
            ) {
                currentWebContents.openDevTools();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Be aware that this allows any user of the production electron app to access dev tools with the common keyboard shortcuts (function: F12 or ctrl + shift + I on PC, cmd + option + i on Mac).

One thing that did **not** work for me was passing this to the BrowserWindow constructor:

```html
webPreferences: {
    devTools: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, Electron can't understand the path to the application folder you provided. You must provide the relative or absolute path to the application directory that holds `package.json` in it. E.g., if `package.json` file of your app is located at `/home/user/my_awesome_app/package.json` then in order to start the app you must issue the following command:

```bash
electron /home/user/my_awesome_app
```

Also note that `main` property in `package.json` file indicates the entry point for your application. In your case it must be like this:

```js
 "main": "src/main.js"
```

Comment: Yes, I've already done that part, I was able to run my app well.
The problem only occurs when I try to add the `react-devtools` for debugging purposes. That's when the error pops out.

Comment: What kind of error do you get when you call `addDevToolsExtension`?

Comment: `The app provided is not a valid electron app, please read the docs on how to write one..blabla` it appears when I add the line `require('remote').require('browser-window').addDevToolsExtension('../react-devtools')`

You can refer to my project structure above for reference.

Comment: Oh, I did not notice one important fact first. `remote` module is used for remote method invocation of main process from renderer process. It doesn't work vice versa. It must be clear for you that `browser-window` is created in the main process and is controlled by the main process. So, in order to add React developer tools from the renderer you should issue the same command on the renderer's side (e.g., inside index.html): `require('remote').require('browser-window').addDevToolsExtension('react-devt‌​ools')`.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the application is the name of the folder which contains all the tree of your application. So, to execute, you have to write, in case your folder is named Electron for example;

```sh
electron Electron
```

Always in prompt in the path that your folder is located.
Hope this help.

(Sorry for my English, a little rusty)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Solution for Electron >= 1.2.1 version

1- In your app folder

```sh
npm install --save-dev electron-react-devtools
```

2- Open your electron app, click on (view/toggle developer tools). In the **console** tab insert the following code and **hit enter**:

```js
require('electron-react-devtools').install()
```

3- Reload/refresh your electron app page and you'll see the react dev tools appear.

4- Done!

---

**See screen shots bellow**

[image: Paste/type code on console tab]

[image: hit enter]

[image: react dev tools enabled]

Answer (score 0):

I know this might not be how to install `devtools`, but i found the `alert` is rewired in the `electron` for the webviews. What that means is that anytime you can shoot this to see simple style.

```
  alert('123')
```

For complex stuff, i believe webview also has a executeJavascript function, maybe you can run `console.log` there.