# How to get dev tools in electron app after packaging? ( electron app = angular2 + typescript)

Tags: angular, google-chrome-devtools, electron, typescript2.0, electron-builder

How can I toggle devTool in electron app after packaging. I developed this app in angular2. So, I just want to have a button which will toggle devTool on demand.

Thank you!

Comment: Consider https://stackoverflow.com/a/61281774/2604813

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [Electron API documentation](http://electron.atom.io/docs/all/#contentsopendevtoolsoptions), this should do the trick:

```
let win = new BrowserWindow()
win.webContents.openDevTools()
```

If you want to connect the openDevTools function to a button click or keyboard shortcut, you'll have to wire it to your renderer process via [IPC](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-main/).

Comment: Above two lines are for JavaScript and I want to add the same in typescript. Any idea...?

Comment: TypeScript is (mostly) a superset of JavaScript, which means that with very few exceptions all JS is valid TS. The above code will work fine in your Typescript files.