# How to debug electron production binaries

Tags: electron

I can't open devtools in the built version of my electron app. Therefore i want to find another solution to log any errors that only occur in the production version.

Is there any good way to get some console.logs from an electron application if its already built?
Obviously i can debug the “development” version (running npm run dev) of my electron app by opening the chrome dev tools. But i can’t find any way to enable them inside my production application.
I am using the newsest version of [electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue)

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: as far as I know, the electron-vue contains a quite old verion of electron (2.0.4) , while the latest electron version is 15.0

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Enabling the Chrome developer tools in production could be done in various ways:

1. Use an environment variable and check `process.env` if it was set:

   - E.g. under Windows `set ELECTRON_ENV=development && myapp.exe`
2. Pass a special parameter or flag to your app and check `process.argv` if it was set.

   - E.g. `myapp.exe --debug`
     Note that the `--debug` flag is an alias for `--inspect` which enables debugging of the main process via websocket, see [Supported Command Line Switches - Node.js Flags](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/command-line-switches#nodejs-flags))
3. If you have persistent settings, then you could create a debug option in your settings.
4. If you have a menu bar, then you can create an entry to open the developer tools. You can always show that entry or you could combine options 1.-3. to only have that menu entry visible when your "debug mode" is enabled.

The developer tools can be opened via [`win.webContents.openDevTools`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentsopendevtoolsoptions) on any window. For small windows I would suggest opening the developer tools either in `detach` or `undocked` mode.

Personally I use a combination of 1., 3. and 4. I simply unlock a developer menu that allows me to open the devtools or opens the userdata folder for me.

---

If you also want to log critical errors, then [electron-log](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-log) looks like a rather popular option for electron.

Comment: not works for me (on Mac). Execute with  `--remote-debugging-port=8315` and open `http://localhost:8315` works. ref: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/3331

Comment: If this answer doesn't work for you, consider https://stackoverflow.com/a/61281774/2604813

Comment: That `--debug`  argument saved my ass... Very useful to inspect executable console messages!

Comment: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. Please use `node --inspect` and `node --inspect-brk` instead.

Comment: @jscripter according to docs for the electron CLI flags, `--debug` is still a valid option/alias to enable debugging.

Answer (score 58):

Here's what worked for me on Mac.

1. In terminal type `lldb path/to/build.app`
2. In the opened debugger type `run --remote-debugging-port=8315`. It should open a window of your app.
3. Open Chrome at `http://localhost:8315/`
4. Click on the name of the app. For example, `Webpack App`.
5. If you don't see anything in the opened tab, focus on the window of your app.

Comment: Anyone ever run into a situation where the packaged .app works if it's started through this lldb -> run method, but if the .app file is started through Finder, but stays on a loading screen indefinitely?  Making it so frustratingly difficult to find the root cause of the issue!  This lldb method has been my go-to!

Comment: I’m hitting `error: process exited with status -1`, not sure yet whether this is related to my app’s issues or me using `lldb` wrong

Comment: For those running into the same issue, `./dist/mac/<your product identifier>.app/Contents/MacOS/<your product identifier> --remote-debugging-port=8315` may at least give a glimpse as to where the error is thrown, since it’ll log to console. I couldn’t get to a stage where `http://127.0.0.1:8315` shows anything, though.

Comment: FYI guys, if you get `error: process exited with status -1` make sure you have the debugging entitlements set, `<key>com.apple.security.cs.debugger</key>` set to `true`.

Answer (score 30):

Launch your Electron application with the `--remote-debugging-port=8315` flag set and navigate to `chrome://inspect/#devices` in Chrome 80+. Then click <kbd>Configure...</kbd> and add `localhost:8315` as a discovery server.

Then, wait for your Electron instance to appear in the devices list and click <kbd>inspect</kbd>.

Answer (score 24):

On Mac just run `open /Applications/WhatsApp.app --args --remote-debugging-port=8315` and then open `http://localhost:8315`

Comment: So was for me on Windows, --args was necessary for some reason

Answer (score 15):

https://github.com/bytedance/debugtron

Debugtron is an app to debug in-production Electron based app. It is also built with Electron.

Comment: Old one but still works and helped me debug. It's worth noting that you might need the following in your main.js for Debugtron to connect to the app

 `app.commandLine.appendSwitch('remote-allow-origins', 'devtools://devtools');`

Answer (score 5):

The way to do this is using the `--remote-debugging-port` flag.

Using Signal as an example, take the following steps:

1. start the application from the CLI

```
signal-desktop --remote-debugging-port
```

2. Open the debugging URL in a Google Chrome browser (in this case `http://localhost:39733/`), this will open a page with the app name on it
    [image].
3. Click the to open a screen were you can click around to use the app and see output in the devtools
    [image: List item]

Alternatively, you can open `chrome://inspect/#devices` in the Google Chrome browser and click "inspect" (underneath the app name) to open the same window 
 [image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a runtime error crashing Electron before the web view was even shown. Chrome dev tools were not useful for debugging this kind of error.

Even stranger, the app loaded fine using the lldb commands:

```bash
lldb ./dist/mac/electron-quick-start-typescript.app
run --remote-debugging-port=8315
```

I managed to solve by writing the Node.js console log/error to a file. So I could see the console output:

```ts
import fs from 'fs';
import util  from 'util';

// use a fixed path, to ensure log shows outside Electron dist
const logPath = `/Users/username/Sites/electron-server/debug-${isDev ? 'dev' : 'prod'}.log`;
const logFile = fs.createWriteStream(logPath, { flags: 'w' });
const logStdout = process.stdout;

console.log = function(...args) {
  logFile.write(util.format.apply(null, args) + '\n');
  logStdout.write(util.format.apply(null, args) + '\n');
}
console.error = console.log;
```

I found the error was a relative path issue. When the app is started in production mode the relative path did not point to the correct location.

I solved by using an absolute path, with Electron `getAppPath()` method:

```ts
- './renderer'
+ app.getAppPath() + '/renderer'
```

Answer (score 1):

June 2022 UPDATE:

Devtools can be explicitly enabled through on the BrowserWindow object.

```js
mainWindow = new BrowserWindows({
   ...,
   webPreferences: {
       ...,
       devTools: true,
   }
}
```

And then you can manually open it on load.

```js
mainWindow.on('ready-to-show', () => {
    if (!mainWindow) {
        throw new Error('mainWindow is not defined')
    }
    mainWindow.show()

    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In the main/index.js at the end of section app.on('ready') just add:

mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

Just for debugging, when electron opens an empty window, but the development version works fine, this way is very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above don't help for me. ( those with -remote-debugging-port)

put this code into your main.js or similar file, it will automatically open the dev-tool when started.

```
mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
```