# Opening Chromium DevTools in production builds of Electron apps without source code or build process

Tags: javascript, electron

Is there a way to open devtools on production builds of Electron that were packaged and distributed to you?

For instance, I'd like to poke around Slack's app. I know that it's built in Electron, and I'd like to open devtools to see how some parts of it are built.

On macOS I've tried:

```
ELECTRON_ENV=development /Applications/Slack.app/Contents/MacOS/Slack --debug --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs
```

as well as the usual key combination of Cmd+Option+I and checking for debug menus/views.

None of these seem to make a difference.

Note that there are already a few solutions that recommend you do it programmatically by injecting:

```
  remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().webContents.openDevTools()
```

However I can't do that because I don't have access to the source code or the original build process. Is there a way to trigger devtools externally?

The most promising way I've seen so far is `remote-debugging-port` but I'm not sure it works with production builds.

Comment: This was also posted on reddit, [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/electronjs/comments/atneek/is_there_a_way_to_open_devtools_on_production/?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug electron production binaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45485262/how-to-debug-electron-production-binaries)

Comment: For Slack in particular you can set environment variable `SLACK_DEVELOPER_MENU=1` and then press Ctrl+Alt+I

Answer (score 6):

The way to do this without third-party code is indeed using the `--remote-debugging-port` flag.

Using Signal as an example, take the following steps:

1. start the application from the CLI

```
signal-desktop --remote-debugging-port
```

2. Open the debugging URL in a Google Chrome browser (in this case `http://localhost:39733/`), this will open a page with the app name on it
    [image].
3. Click the to open a screen were you can click around to use the app and see output in the devtools
    [image: List item]

Alternatively, you can open `chrome://inspect/#devices` in the Google Chrome browser and click "inspect" (underneath the app name) to open the same window 
 [image]