# Selenium webdriver not working in Electron build

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, electron, electron-builder

I have an electron project that renders an html page with a button that when clicked calls a node js script (via IPC) which uses selenium to scrape webpages.

here’s my project structure:

```
    -app/
     --index.html
     --main.js
     --index.js
    -package.json
```

Here’s my package.json:

```
    {
        "name": "agencies-scraper",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "main": "app/main.js",
        "devDependencies": {
            "electron": "^5.0.7",
            "electron-builder": "^21.1.1"
        },
        "scripts": {
            "start": "electron .",
            "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
            "dist": "electron-builder",
            "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
        },
        "build": {
            "appId": "my.id",
            "files": [
                "app/**/*",
                "node_modules/**/*",
                "package.json"
            ],
            "mac": {
                "category": "your.app.category.type"
            },
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "csv-writer": "^1.5.0",
            "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.4"
        }
    }
```

In index.html I have a button:

```
    <button id="test">Click to Scrape</button>
```

When clicked it fires the following chain of reactions:

1. The linked index.js, send a signal to the “backchannel” ipc channel:

```
    const {ipcRenderer} = require("electron");
    const button = document.getElementById("test");
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      ipcRenderer.send("backchannel"); 
    }
```

2. In main.js, I listen to “backchannel”, and when triggered, instantiate a selenium webdriver and open google.com in a separate chrome browser:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron')
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver')

ipcMain.on('backchannel', async (event, arg) => {
    const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
            .forBrowser('chrome')
            .build()
    try {
        await driver.get('https://google.com');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

3. The os asks if I want the electron app to accept incoming connections and I click “Allow” (selenium opens a browser regardless):
   [image: Permission popup screenshot]

This works perfectly when I work in development via `npm start`.

However, when I package the app either via `npm run-script pack` or `npm run-script dist`, the build version does not reach step 3. No permission window pops up and no browser opens. Selenium just doesn’t work there.

I am sure the IPC is working from index.js to main.js in the build version so the issue is not with that. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56634497/4573129) helped me to debug the issue

I'm quoting it in case it gets deleted

> 1. In terminal type `lldb path/to/build.app`
> 2. In the opened debugger type `run --remote-debugging-port=8315`. It should open a window of your app.
> 3. Open Chrome at `http://localhost:8315/`
> 4. Click on the name of the app. For example, `Webpack App`.
> 5. If you don't see anything in the opened tab, focus on the window of your app.

Then in the terminal, check for this error:

`The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH. Please download the latest version of the ChromeDriver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and ensure it can be found on your PATH.`

if that is the case, then [download the latest version of chromedriver](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) and add the binaries to the root of your project.

Run the build again and it should work!

**Edit:**
The problem you are facing is that binaries inside app.asar cannot be executed, so, a quick fix for this:

On your package.json, add the following property to the "build" object

`"asar": false`

it should look like this:

```
.
.
.
        "build": {
            "appId": "my.id",
            "asar": false,
            "files": [
                "app/**/*",
                "node_modules/**/*",
                "package.json"
            ],
            "mac": {
                "category": "your.app.category.type"
            },
        },
.
.
.
```

**Edit #2:**

Electron builder automatically unpacks executable binaries, so the following solution worked for me.

run `npm install chromedriver`

on the part you are building the chromedriver, change the way you build it to this:

```
const chromedriverPath = require('chromedriver').path.replace('app.asar', 'app.asar.unpacked');
const serviceBuilder = new ServiceBuilder(chromedriverPath);
let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser("chrome")
  .setChromeService(serviceBuilder)
  .build();
```

This way, the driver gets the correct unpacked path to the chromedriver binary.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the option #1 fixed my issue!