# Chrome Dev tools in electron app?

Tags: node.js, electron

I have found that, while running some Electron app, I can access Chrome Dev Tools by pressing Cmd-Alt-I, while on some others I can't. I am wondering which is the setting to avoid/enable this behaviour.

Comment: Not familiar with Electron but I would imagine they built it as some sort of development version instead of production by accident.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of options. You can initialize your BrowserWindow **without** devtools:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  webPreferences: {
    devTools: false
  }
});
```

Or you can catch the opened **event** on the webContents and close it:

```
mainWindow.webContents.on("devtools-opened", () => {
   mainWindow.webContents.closeDevTools();
});
```

Comment: this is not what I meant.
I have seen apps in which I can open Dev Tools and others in which I can't. I'm asking why it is happening and how to avoid/allow a user to open Dev Tools on my app?

Comment: If you initialize the window with devTools: false the keyboard shortcut won't work. This is probably the case in the app you tried. I hope I'm understanding your question correctly.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But I have never initialized my app with that setting, and it doesn't open Dev Tools either. How to enable Cmd-Alt-I on the app?

Comment: It used to be enabled by default but I believe was disabled with this: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1718

Comment: That's weird... I am running GitHub desktop (latest version) and it is enabled....

Comment: Is the electron-debug package in use? I think it re-enables them. https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-debug

Comment: If this answer doesn't work for you, consider https://stackoverflow.com/a/61281774/2604813