# How to debug electron production

Tags: electron

I can't open chrome dev tools in my built electron app using electron packager.

I have tried `mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()` but this didn't work.

Looking online and at other SO answers, I came across commenting out `rendererConfig.devtool = ''` and `webConfig.devtool = ''` but this didn't make a difference either.

I have also tried adding a key shortcut to open the dev tools but this did nothing.

I am using the latest version of electron.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Not sure why key shortcut didn't work for you; it did for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61281774/2604813

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out that one way to debug the production app is run the .exe from a terminal with the argument `--remote-debugging-port=8315`. This will allow debugging by going to [http://localhost:8315/](http://localhost:8315) in chrome.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me lot.

Answer (score 2):

Register a shortcut in your `main`

```
const ret = globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+Shift+I', () => {
     mainWindow.webContents.toggleDevTools();
});
```

Comment: You need to firstly confirm your electron version, e.g. currently version is 16, and some old version is 2.0.x , so check the API here: https://github.com/electron/electron/tree/v1.4.0

Answer (score 2):

for vue-electron, it's using electron 2.0.x, and you should change src/main/index.js, and also use `openDevTools`, e.g.:

```
import { app, BrowserWindow , globalShortcut} from 'electron'

  const ret = globalShortcut.register('F11', () => {
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
  })
```

and run the production app, press `F11`, you will find the log:

[image]