# How do I see the main console after packaging with electron-forge (squirrel.windows)?

Tags: console, electron-forge

I am just getting started with electron, specifically electron-forge. When running in development mode from the command line using `> npm run start` I can see a console window and also a render window. But after I package the application using `> npm run make`, it generates a windows executable. When I double click that, I have my render window, but there is no console window.

It seems like there should be an option in electron-forge to do the packaging but still have it generate a console window.

Note, I found a way to show `console.log` statements from my main application in a render window by monkey patching `process.stdout.write` and outputting to a string variable which is shared with the render process via IPC, but this seems a little fragile and I would have thought that some way to have a console window after packaging would exist.

Comment: Have you tried simply running the executable from a cmd window?

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean with console. The chrome devTools window?
If you still have the default electron menu bar: you can open it from there.

Otherwise you can add something like that to your code:

```
browserWindow.webContents.openDevTools({ mode: 'detach' });
```

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/application-debugging

if you want to open that with F12, that may help you too:
[How to include Chrome DevTools in Electron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294600/how-to-include-chrome-devtools-in-electron/75716165#75716165)

You could monkey patch process.stdout.write to send to renderer via IPC. in main something like that:

```
mainWindow.webContents.send('my-console', consoleText)
```

and in renderer something like that:

```
ipcRenderer.on('my-console', (event, consoleText) => {
   console.log(consoleText);
});
```

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc#1-send-messages-with-the-webcontents-module